# c++ dynamic array and classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

I am trying to create a dynamic in my assignment. but every time I debug I keep getting the array needs to be a const. how do I fix this. First I am using Visual studio. this is for a class.

my code is

```
 int main()
    {
        int stdno;

        cout << "Enter number of Students :" << endl;
        cin >> stdno;

        Student s1[stdno];

        for (int i = 0; i < stdno; i++)
        {

            s1[i].inputStudentInfo();
        }
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "-------------STUDENT DETAILS------------------" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < stdno; i++)
        {
            s1[i].displayStudentInfo();
            s1[i].computeAvgScore();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `Student s1[stdno];` (Variable Length Array, or VLA) is not standard C++.  You should use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Student s1[stdno];
```

This is not standard in C++. You can use dynamic memory allocation.

```
Student *s1 = new Student[stdno];

delete [] s1;
```

or simply you can use

```
std::vector<Student> student_vec;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer to use a `std::vector` if you need a dynamic (run-time sized) array

```
std::vector<Student> s1(stdno);
```

the rest of your code would then work as written.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting the array needs to be a const

The array sizes need to be a compile time constant, before the program runs.

They are alternatives that are dynamic, such as `std::vector`:

```
int main()
{
    int stdno;

    cout << "Enter number of Students :" << endl;
    cin >> stdno;

    std::vector<Student> s1(stdno);

    for (int i = 0; i < stdno; i++)
    {

        s1[i].inputStudentInfo();
    }
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "-------------STUDENT DETAILS------------------" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < stdno; i++)
    {
        s1[i].displayStudentInfo();
        s1[i].computeAvgScore();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can also use dynamic array allocation, but dynamic allocations are an advanced subject. Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
auto s1 = new Student[stdno];

// ...

delete[] s1;
```

Comment: ok if i add std::vector i get namespace std has no member. all of sudden s1 is now undefined.

Comment: @TonyLaValle Did you `#include <vector>`?